# TouchableHighlight needs two taps to close modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using *react-native-modalbox* component and have an X(close) View in modal which handles modal closing. Problem is that when tapping on X the states are changed but the modal doesn't close, second tap does the trick.

I checked all parent ScrollView(s) of the component and added
**keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'** but no effect. Any suggestions?

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          modalOpen: false,
          swipeToClose: true
        }
  }



  modalVisibility(){
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen
    })
  }

render() {
   return (
       <Modal
          ref={"modal"}
          isOpen={this.state.modalOpen}
          swipeToClose={false}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() => this.modalVisibility()}
              underlayColor="transparent"
              style={styles.closeModal}
              >
              <Text
                X
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
       </Modal>
)
}
```

Comment: You never seem to close Modal. That very well might be the reason this is required

Comment: Hey sorry about that. I edited it. functionality is no problem

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see right off is that you call `modalVisibility()` in two different ways.

1. `this.modalVisibility()`
2. `this.props.modalVisibility()`

The second, attached to the 'X' will call up to the parent, whereas the first will call a method instance. We'd need to see the full components to know what's going on there.

However, since `Modal` takes an `isOpen` value, you should be able to toggle modal visibility within the React Dev Tools itself to help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: Hey Chris, sorry about that. I edited it. there is no problem with functionality I think because when i click it the first time the state changes but the modal doesn't close and on second click it closes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Much better!

Are you able to open/close by changing state in the react dev tools? Any chance you'd be willing to setup a demo on jsfiddle or code sandbox?